# system.dllnotfoundexception without VS 2008

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2008, dll

My C# code loads a C++ DLL. It works fine on my PC, where Visual Studio 2008 is installed. But on other machines the program stop with an exception

```
Unhandeled exception: system.dllnotfoundexception unable to load dll ... 
this application has failed becasue the application configuration is incorrect....
```

How can I make this code run on a machine that doesn't have VS 2008 installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in vs 2008 on project:
Properties>c/c++ >Runtime Library > choose: Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)

Answer (score 1):

You must distribute your DLL along with your project if it is a custom DLL of yours. If not, you must install the required DLL either with a custom installer or if it is from a different provider, a installer of them.

[This](http://thewayofcoding.com/2008/03/dll-files-and-net-clickonce-deployment/) post might be a bit older, but

DLL Files And .NET ClickOnce Deployment

I want to deploy one of my .NET apps as a ClickOnce application. The issue is that I am connecting to Oracle (see previous posts here and here). Connecting to Oracle requires at least, 4 DLL files that generally have to be in the same directory as the EXE file. The issue is that when the program is published, the DLLs are not referenced in any way, so the program won’t work.

Then I read about adding the files to the project, so that ClickOnce and the Publish processor will figure out that the DLLs are required and add them to the manifest.

```
Here is the process in Visual Studio 2005:  
1. Put the 4 DLL files in their own directory in your solution directory (for ease of use mostly).  
2. Add all four files to your project by going to “Project->Add Existing Item…”  
3. Click on each DLL file in the solution explorer and then change their property: “Copy To Output Directory” to “Copy Always”.
```

That’s it! Now when I publish or even run the application I don’t have to worry about if the DLL files are where they should be.